# Entity reference through lookup

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

/* I created a customised entity name "Account copy". When I create a record in "Account" entity then copy of that record is also created in "Account Copy". So far so good but when I try to update Account entity record then Account copy entity record should also be updated.For this I need entity reference through lookup field which I am unable to figure out. Please guide me.*/

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

namespace CreateUpdate
{
    public class CreateUpdate : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity && context.InputParameters != null)
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
                if (entity.LogicalName != "account") return;

                else if (entity.LogicalName == "account")
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (context.MessageName == "Create")
                        {
                            //call create method
                            CreateRecord(service, entity);
                        }

                        else if (context.MessageName == "Update")
                        {
                            //call Update method
                            UpdateRecord(context, service, entity);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        private static void CreateRecord(IOrganizationService service, Entity account)
        {
            var accountcopy = new Entity("new_accountcopy");
            accountcopy["new_name"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
            accountcopy["new_phone"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone1");
            accountcopy["new_fax"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("fax");
            accountcopy["new_website"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("websiteurl");
            service.Create(accountcopy);

        EntityReference Entref = (EntityReference)account.Attributes["accountid"];
        Guid LookupId = Entref.Id;
        string logicalName = Entref.LogicalName;
        accountcopy["new_accountcopyid"]= new EntityReference(logicalName, LookupId);
        accountcopy["new_accountcopyid"] = null;
        }

        private static void UpdateRecord(IPluginExecutionContext context, IOrganizationService service, Entity account)
        {
            account.Attributes["name"] = "Max";
            account.Attributes["telephone1"] = "+422565895";
            account.Attributes["fax"] = "+426565898";
            account.Attributes["websiteurl"] = "www.max.com";

            if (context.Depth <= 1)
            {
                service.Update(account);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any followup questions?

Comment: thanks for the help.there are still few errors but I think i can manage them. thanks once again

Comment: Hi Arun, I have few follow up questions. First the below line gives me error that "'new_accountcopy' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name = 'accountid' and NameMapping = 'Logical'." ***/accountCopy["accountid"] = new EntityReference("account", entity.Id);--- and my second question is that what do you mean target.id in this line of code "toUpdate.Id = target.Id;".

Comment: you may need to use either one of my below code based on your relationship, not both. Read my answer thoroughly, also some documentation to understand crm terminologies. Target is variable from input param Target, you named it as entity.

Comment: Thanks, i am using one of them. Well i am still very new to this as you have figured it out. Anyway i will keep your advice in count. Thanks for help and can you please suggest any book or link for detailed plug in development in dynamics 365?

Comment: Refer this: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/195080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this plugin is registered in Post-operation on Create message of `account` entity, assuming `new_accountcopy` entity got `accountid` lookup relationship, the below code will work.

```
Entity accountCopy = new Entity("new_accountcopy");

accountCopy["new_name"] = entity.Attributes["name"];
accountCopy["new_phone"] = entity.Attributes["telephone1"];
accountCopy["new_fax"] = entity.Attributes["fax"];
accountCopy["new_website"] = entity.Attributes["websiteurl"];
accountCopy["accountid"] = new EntityReference("account", entity.Id); //mapping the account lookup in account-copy record

service.Create(accountCopy);
```

Extra tip: `string LookUpaccountName = entref.LogicalName;` is right way

**Update**: We are talking about two different things - mapping relational lookup & then using that lookup syncing the data from further updates.

**Scenario 1** (this was your original question)

When you create a new account record - post create plugin on **account** entity creates **account-copy** record & either one of that record will have reference to other record in lookup. I would assume this relationship will never change - no need to sync in update of account record.

If you have `accountid` lookup in `new_accountcopy` entity - my above code works.
(Or)
If you have `new_accountcopyid` lookup in `account` entity, then follow this code:

```
Guid createdId = service.Create(accountcopy);

Entity toUpdate = new Entity("account");
toUpdate.Id = entity.Id;
toUpdate["new_accountcopyid"]= new EntityReference("new_accountcopy", createdId); //mapping the account-copy lookup in account record
service.Update(toUpdate);
```

**Scenario 2**

On future updates of main account, you can retrieve the related **account-copy** record & update it with **account** changes.

Note: Keep the plugin in Asynchronous mode.

Comment: the extra tip you gave, can you please tell me how to do it. thanks

Comment: @ManiMir I just said - instead of `entref.Name` you should give `entref.LogicalName` as Name is display name of that record whereas LogicalName will give entity name like account

Comment: Thanks for  your help. I tried that and somehow i still cant get my desired results. I have updated my code, Can you please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea about how you could handle it (and please note I didn't test this code):

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
    ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

    IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
    IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity && context.InputParameters != null )
    {
        Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

        if (entity.LogicalName == "account")
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateInsertAccountCopy(entity);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}

public void UpdateInsertAccountCopy(Entity account)
{   
    //whether it is a create or an update, set the fields on a new entity object
    var copy = new Entity("new_accountcopy");
    copy["new_name"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");
    copy["new_phone"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("telephone1");
    copy["new_fax"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("fax");
    copy["new_website"] = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("websiteurl");

    //if there is an existing AccountCopy
    if(account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_accountcopyid") != null
    {
        //set the Id on the new copy entity object
        copy.Id = account.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("new_accountcopyid").Id;
        //then update it
        service.Update(copy);
    }
    //otherwise, create the AccountCopy
    else
    {
        service.Create(copy);
    }           
}
```

And, you might want to add handling for delete of an Account to also delete the AccountCopy.

Comment: hi, thanks for the help. the code works fine without any error but when i update the record in the account entity then it should also update in then account copy entity, which i not the case. it remains the same. Please can you provide me little feedback on that as well.

Comment: You're welcome. Do you have a separate plugin step registered on the `update` message of the Account entity?

Comment: no both are registered on the create message. Should i update the code

Comment: I have updated my code now it is registered on both create and update message steps. now how can i achieve the entity reference through Lookup so that if one entity record is updated then the related records are also updated.

Comment: Glad to hear that it's working. What do you mean by "how can I achieve the entity reference through Lookup"? The best way might be to post code of how you're attempting to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my code.you can see it above i  the main question. What i am trying to do is when i create new record in account entity then a copy of that record is also created in custom "account copy" entity. Its fine till this part. What i cannot figure out is that when i update the account record, it should be automatically be updated in account copy entity record. I want to do this with entity reference via lookup field. And this also have 1:N relationship.